# Freemarker: generate UUID conveniently

Tags: java, freemarker, uuid

There seems to be no convenient built-in in Freemarker to generate a random UUID in a template.

The best I could come up with was by creating a [Freemarker method](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html); in my Java 8 code I inject the method for later usage in the template. Example:

```
public String generate(Map<String, Object> data, String templateLocation) throws IOException, TemplateException {
    try (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
        Template template = configuration.getTemplate(templateLocation);
        // UUID generation method injected in this line:
        data.put("uuid", (TemplateMethodModelEx) (list) -> UUID.randomUUID());
        template.process(data, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

In the Freemarker template I can then use the method like this:

```
${uuid()}
```

Is there a more convenient solution to generate uuids in Freemarker?

Here is the my Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.25-incubating</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [statics](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_60) to call `randomUUID` in your template:

```
${statics["java.util.UUID"].randomUUID()}
```

> This object exposes just about any class' static methods if it's used as a hash with class name as the key.

Comment: i add it as ```<#assign id =statics["java.util.UUID"].randomUUID() >``` but it says statics  is undefined in ftl file

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov add **statics** to the map, e. g.

`root.put("statics", new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31).build().getStaticModels());`

Answer (score 2):

You may add that method to the configuration globally with `Configuration.setSharedVariable(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value of UUID.randomUUID() on configuration freemarker like this

```
public freemarker.template.Configuration configuration() throws TemplateModelException {
        freemarker.template.Configuration cfg = new freemarker.template.Configuration(freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_24);

        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("path/of/freemarker/template"));
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
        cfg.setSharedVariable("UUID", UUID.randomUUID());

        return cfg;
    }
```

in the template you can use this

```
"var":"${UUID}"
```

Note: you can change "UUID" for another value on configuration of freemarker and template.